# mysql ORDER BY and CASE casts INT to CHAR?

Tags: mysql, casting, sql-order-by

For a stored procedure with configurable sort order (_Sort parameter), i use code like this:

```
    SELECT * FROM distances   
    ORDER BY 
        CASE _Sort 
            WHEN 1 THEN uid
            WHEN 2 THEN NULL
            WHEN 3 THEN name
            WHEN 4 THEN NULL
            WHEN 5 THEN distance
            WHEN 6 THEN NULL
            ELSE distance
        END ASC,
        CASE _Sort 
            WHEN 2 THEN uid
            WHEN 4 THEN name
            WHEN 6 THEN distance
            ELSE NULL
        END DESC
```

in which `uid` is **INT** and `distance` is **DOUBLE**.

But if _Sort = 1, `uid` is ordered like it was a **CHAR** e.g.

```
200
207
 25
  4
```

Same thing for `distance`.
Casting to unsigned and decimal did not help.

`ORDER BY uid ASC` does the right thing, i.e. `4, 25, 200, 207`

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution (**edited**) -

```
SELECT * FROM distances
ORDER BY
  IF(_Sort = 1, uid, 0),
  IF(_Sort = 2, NULL, 0),
  IF(_Sort = 3, name, 0),
  IF(_Sort = 4, NULL, 0),
  ...
```

Comment: I'm using this code now: `ORDER BY IF(_Sort=1,uid,NULL) ASC, IF(_Sort=2,uid,NULL) DESC, IF(_Sort=3,name,NULL) ASC, ..., IFNULL(_Sort,name) ASC`

Answer (score 1):

As documented under [Control Flow Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case):

> The return type of a `CASE` expression is the compatible aggregated type of all return values

Whilst the manual does not explicitly document how the "compatible aggregated type" is determined, one can follow the source from [`Item_func_case::fix_length_and_dec()`](http://fossies.org/dox/mysql-5.5.30/item__cmpfunc_8cc_source.html#l03070) through [`agg_result_type()`](http://fossies.org/dox/mysql-5.5.30/item__cmpfunc_8cc_source.html#l00076) to [`item_store_type()`](http://fossies.org/dox/mysql-5.5.30/item__cmpfunc_8cc_source.html#l00039):

```
static Item_result item_store_type(Item_result a, Item *item,
                                   my_bool unsigned_flag)
{
  Item_result b= item->result_type();

  if (a == STRING_RESULT || b == STRING_RESULT)
    return STRING_RESULT;
  else if (a == REAL_RESULT || b == REAL_RESULT)
    return REAL_RESULT;
  else if (a == DECIMAL_RESULT || b == DECIMAL_RESULT ||
           unsigned_flag != item->unsigned_flag)
    return DECIMAL_RESULT;
  else
    return INT_RESULT;
}
```

One can therefore see that if a single return value is a string, then the return value of the overall `CASE` expression will also be a string.

In your case, one presumes that `name` is a string; therefore the data type returned by your `CASE` expression is a string.  Consequently, your numeric values are compared as strings and thus sorted lexicographically (hence the output that you observe).

One way of overcoming this would be to pad all numeric values to equal widths in order that sorting lexicographically will deliver the desired results: using the `ZEROFILL` attribute of integer-type columns will do this automatically; however, this is still pretty inefficient and you may wish to consider redesigning your logic.

For example, you could instead build a string that contains the desired SQL; then [prepare and execute](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) a statement from that string:

```sql
SET @sql := CONCAT(
  'SELECT * FROM distances ORDER BY ',
  CASE _Sort
    WHEN 1 THEN 'uid ASC'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'uid DESC'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'name ASC'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'name DESC'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'distance ASC'
    WHEN 6 THEN 'distance DESC'
    ELSE 'distance ASC'
  END
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Very good explanation, thanks. Prepared statement was my first idea but then i used the CASE expression because it's more straight forward... So using `IF(..)`is the better solution for me.